# Simplify the templating of Oracle configuration file based on a dictionary

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I am trying to use a template which generate the config file containing tinformations like the hosts, port, username, password, ...
I want to use one template and pass the tag in the template task, so the template will pick variables which are defined within the corresponding tag, i.e.:

```yaml
- name: generate config
  template:
    src: /test/debezium_oracle_cdc_source.j2
    dest: "/config/debz-oracle-test_1.json"
  vars:
    tags: "{{ oracle['tag1']  }}"
    bootstrap_servers: "kafka:9092"

- name: generate config
  template:
    src: /test/debezium_oracle_cdc_source.j2
    dest: "/config/debz-oracle-test_2.json"
  vars:
    tags: "{{ oracle['tag2']  }}"
    bootstrap_servers: "kafka:9092"
```

My variable file

```yaml
oracle:
   tag1:
       tables:
         - DEPT
         - EMPLOYEE
      db_host: localhost
      db_name: root
      db_user: root
      db_port: 1521
      
  tag2:
       tables:
         - SALES
         - SALES_ITEM
      db_host: localhost
      db_name: root
      db_user: root
      db_port: 1521
```

*debezium_oracle_cdc_source.j2*:

```json
{
  "database.hostname": "{{ db_host }}",
  "database.port": "{{ db_port }}"
}
```

Basically, I want to make my variable file more readable.

Comment: And, what is not working with what you are showing here?

Comment: template is not able to get db_host and properties defined within tag1

Comment: How to you try to access them? What is the content of the Jinja template?

Comment: Like this                                                                                           "database.hostname": "{{db_host}}",
 "database.port": "{{db_port}}"

Comment: Should be `"database.hostname": "{{ tags.db_host }}"` and `"database.port": "{{ tags.db_port }}"`, as you assigned those dictionary to `tags`.

Comment: Ok got it, but how I can pass this reference to template task , I mean how can I pass the reference to use tag1.I have used the below code and it is not working - name: generate config
      template:
        src: /test/debezium_oracle_cdc_source.j2
        dest: "/config/debz-oracle-test_2.json"
      vars:
        tags: "{{ oracle['tag2']  }}"
        bootstrap_servers: "kafka:9092"

Comment: This is exactly what you are doing there. Please have a read at [mre], and [edit] your question to show a reproducible example.

Comment: But I have given the code to reproduce what I have been asking

Comment: No, it is not, you are not showing us the error message, nor the content of the template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the fact that `tags` is a reserved word in Ansible, because it is an existing *[keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html)*.

This can be reproduced and confirmed with a simple task like:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ tags }}"
  vars:
    tags: I guess I am buggy?
```

Which does error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
    The error was: 'tags' is undefined. 'tags' is undefined
  
    The error appears to be in '/usr/local/ansible/play.yml': 
    line 7, column 7, but may be elsewhere in the file 
    depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
      tasks:
        - debug:
          ^ here
```

This can be easily fixed, for example, by prefixing the variable with an underscore:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ _tags }}"
  vars:
    _tags: I guess I am buggy?
```

This yields the expected:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: I guess I am buggy?
```

---

So in your case with the template *debezium_oracle_cdc_source.j2* containing:

```json
{
  "database.hostname": "{{ _tags.db_host }}",
  "database.port": "{{ _tags.db_port }}"
}
```

And the task:

```yaml
- template:
    src: debezium_oracle_cdc_source.j2
    dest: "/config/debz-oracle-test_{{ item }}.json"
  loop: "{{ range(1, 3) }}"
  vars:
    _tags: "{{ oracle['tag' ~ item]  }}"
    oracle:
      tag1:
          db_host: host1.localhost
          db_port: 1234
      tag2:
          db_host: host2.localhost
          db_port: 5678
```

We do get the two expected JSON:

- */config/debz-oracle-test_1.json*:

  ```json
  {
    "database.hostname": "host1.localhost",
    "database.port": "1234"
  }
  ```
- */config/debz-oracle-test_2.json*:

  ```json
  {
    "database.hostname": "host2.localhost",
    "database.port": "5678"
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks , it worked !! Sorry for initial description from next time will try to post as much as possible in description

Answer (score 0):

Use the dictionary *tags* in the template

```yaml
{
  "database.hostname": "{{ tags.db_host }}",
  "database.port": "{{ tags.db_port }}"
}
```